# Нарисовать линию в picture_box

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь нарисовать линию:

```
private void pic_move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    picture_form2.Invalidate();
}

private void repaint_img(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(picture_form2.Image);
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255), 8);
    pen.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
    g.DrawLine(pen, mouse_x_arrow, mouse_y_arrow, Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X, Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y);
}
```

Но выглядит это бесконечно размазанной стрелкой: http://yadi.sk/d/N3KN03cTNu2SV

Из-за чего подобное может происходить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие `MouseMove` вызывается каждый раз, когда меняется положение мыши над контролом. Поэтому когда вы двигаете мышь, постоянно рисуются новые стрелки. Как, к примеру, можно это обойти: при MouseDown вы сохраняете содержимое PictureBox в переменную, и каждый раз в MouseMove рисуете сначала сохраненное изображение, а поверх него новую стрелку